# Are line-breaks in question titles allowed?

Tags: discussion

This post has line breaks in the title, making it appear to be 4 separate lines:

[Is the Nyquist plot a plot of $$\text{Re}(G(s)) \text{v.s.} \text{Im}(G(s))$$ or $$\text{Re}(G(j\omega)) \text{v.s.} \text{Im}(G(j\omega))$$](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270722/is-the-nyquist-plot-a-plot-of-textregs-textv-s-textimgs-or)

---

It appears as such even in the list of ["Top Questions"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

[image: screencap]

Is that kosher?

Comment: For information, on android with the official SE application, this title became absolutely unreadable, since mathjax wasn't interpreted and was just shown raw. So I'd say you'd better avoid it.

Comment: Related: on [math.se], displayed formulas in titles are blocked automatically, try for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=$$%5Csin%5E2x%20%5Ccos%5E2x%20=%201$$  (but Math sites allows inline formulas in titles).

Comment: To wit, line breaks, or html arn't allowed in the title, this was an issue with styling of mathjax.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like the single-line format of Mathjax was called (`$$`), instead of the inline version (`\$`) which resulted in each Mathjax segment receiving its own line.

Mathjax in the titles should be avoided - alt codes are a reasonable substitution for most needs. Adding Mathjax in the title is undesirable because it makes it difficult for mobile users, and loading Mathjax makes the main screen less responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the system allows it, although that may be just a consequence of enabling MathJax and not a deliberate decision by the developers.

Even so, it is a **bad idea** at best, and should be discouraged.

Titles aren't for asking questions or supplying information to the question.  Their purpose is to give people a quick one-line (or less) idea of what the question is about.  Multiple lines in a title don't serve this purpose, and actually make using the title more difficult for everyone else.

You might consider downvoting questions that have this little respect for the reader, or try to use trickery to get more attention.

Comment: How can I forward this issue to the right person? As user "dim" said: *"on android with the official SE application, this title became absolutely unreadable, since mathjax wasn't interpreted and was just shown raw."* So clearly, mathjax needs to be disabled in the title field.